# The signal $\cos(2 \pi t )$ is an eigenfunction of every LTI system?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

for $\sin(2 \pi t)$:
Apparently that it's *not* an eigenfunction real-valued impulse response $h(t)$
but it's a eigenfunction for real-valued and **even** impulse response $h(t)$

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what gives: the actual eigenfunctions are those of the form $e^{i\omega t}$.  In particular, we have
$$
h(t)*e^{i\omega t} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{i\omega (t-\tau)}\,d\tau
= \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau)e^{-i\omega \tau}\,d\tau\right]e^{i\omega t}
:= H(\omega)e^{i\omega t}
$$
It follows that
$$
h(t)*\cos(\omega t) = h(t) * \frac 12 \left[e^{i \omega t} + e^{-i \omega t} \right]
= \frac12 \left[H(\omega)e^{i \omega t} + H(-\omega)e^{-i \omega t}\right]
$$
This will be a multiple of the original function exactly when $H(\omega) = H(-\omega)$.  So, as long as $H(2 \pi) = H(- 2 \pi)$, $\cos(2 \pi t)$ will be an eigenfunction.